# can i search for the photo_id in photo_src table using the photo url?

Tags: php, facebook-fql, photo

I am trying to use FQL to get the photo id of a profile picture. Is this possible using the new photo_src table?

it returns the following error:
"url is not a member of the photo_src table"

even though as it can be seen in the docs at ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_src/ ) URL is a member

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referred to facebook developer documentation at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_src/) page

According to the below

[image]

only the column which is marked as `indexable` can be used to query the table(photo_src) and not the other columns.

Also refer to the example, only the indexable column can be used to query the table

> SELECT src, width, height FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id =
>   10150931418786729

**EDIT:**

**Trick:** 
This is a trick which I used and is similar to what Mr Tom Waddington has explained in this answer below, but which a small change.

**URL:** https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/s720x720/423961_3099973533075_1076266190_3040344_2138806733_n.jpg

`1076266190` - User ID (UID)

`3099973533075` - Photo ID

Comment: thanks for the answer i wasnt sure what indexable meant. i'm surprised though that this is the case since they have an example where they use width and height in the query in addition to photo_id. I take it there is no way to get the photo_id of an event profile picture?

Comment: updated my answer, and please do consider tagging your question as answered if you have found your answer :)

Comment: by the way I still cannot get it to work. I am not sure its possible at all. For example I get the following profile photo from an event:

http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/373038_410259388992681_1536622318_n.jpg

410259388992681 should be the photoid so the query should look like this: 

SELECT src, width, height FROM photo_src WHERE photo_id = 410259388992681

When executed returns an empty array. No error. Does that mean event profile photos are not in photo_src table?

Answer (score 0):

I think all photo urls contain the Facebook UID of the photo.

Example:
http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/562281_10150798057523523_511353522_11470130_1470687243_n.jpg

UID is 10150798057523523.

So, you could parse the URL you have and find the photo UID.